OK to Delete *.post Files after Upgrading Git on Windows?
I just upgraded Git (from Git Bash CLI, running git update-git-for-windows) & got "Permission denied" on 4 files in /etc/post-install/ directory.
Is there any reason NOT to delete these files? (Specific file names: 01-devices.post, 03-mtab.post, 06-windows-files.post. and 99-post-install-cleanup.post.)
Haven't tried anything yet
